# Use sed to modify and execute previous command

Tags: command-line, bash, unix, sed

I've got a bunch of pdf files that are joined with a very long command line sitting in a directory. Some are in English and some are in French, differentiated by `_e.pdf` and `_f.pdf`.

Because they're joined in a specific order the command line can't be shortened, but I'd like to modify and re-execute it, simply replacing `_e` by `_f`.  How can I use `sed` (or other) for this?

Let's say the command is

```
pdfjoin file1_e.pdf file2_e.pdf file3_e.pdf
```

and in history it's command 10.

I've got as far as

```
echo !10 | sed 's/_e.pdf/_f.pdf/g'
```

which echoes the command I want to run. But I actually want to run that, not just display the command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried backticks?

```
`echo !10 | sed 's/_e.pdf/_f.pdf/g'`
```

Though I can't help feeling that you should be using `make`.

Answer (score 0):

By the way GNU sed has more interesting trick to execute commands:

```
echo !10 | sed 's/_e.pdf/_f.pdf/ge'
```